# Joi.js return a weird error message

Tags: joi

I'm using [joi](https://github.com/hapijs/joi) to validate my apis request. All things is good except the error message return the field name with slash '\' character.

```
{
  "message": "validation error",
  "error": {
    "status": 400,
    "statusText": "Bad Request",
    "errors": [
      {
        "field": "email",
        "location": "body",
        "messages": [
          "\"email\" must be a valid email"
        ],
        "types": [
          "string.email"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Anyone got this problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your variable names are put in quotes by default and those quotes are [escaped with the backslash character](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notation). I couldn't find much on the reason for this so maybe someone else can weigh in there.

But to override this behavior, you can [override the `language` option](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v8.0.5/API.md#validatevalue-schema-options-callback) when you call `joi.validate()` and pass in an optional `options` parameter. This example just overrides the escaping for strings.

```
var joi = require('joi');

var schema = joi.object().keys({
    name: joi.string().required()
});

var x = {
    name: 123
};

var options = {
    language: {
        string: {
            base: '{{key}} must be a string'
        }
    }
};

var result = joi.validate(x, schema, options);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

To override escape characters for all types, specify a `key` parameter in your `options`. Note the space at the end.

```
var options = {
    language: {
        key: '{{key}} '
    }
};
```

More detailed examples on how to override `language` can be found [here](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v8.0.5/lib/language.js).

Answer (score 1):

As of `Joi` version [17.0.0](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/issues/2262) you can use `label: ''` in order to remove the  double quote as part of the options:

```
 const options = {
      errors: {
        wrap: {
          label: false
        }
      }
    };


var result = schema.validate(x, options);
```